# Private access for a SP working on a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-key, nonclustered-index

I have a Stored Procedure that is dropping, recreating and then applying keys and indexes to a table, but the process gets interrupted by other database tasks and then fails to apply the require keys and indexes.

The table is considered the main table within the Db and gets accessed later on by many apps and website so it is crucial that the indexes get applied.

Are there any tools within SQL Server that will allow me to isolate access to the newly made table until the keys and indexes have been applied ?

Comment: 'process gets interrupted by other database tasks and then fails to apply the require keys and indexes' You're going to need to clarify what you mean by 'interrupted' and 'fails'.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson By interrupted I mean another task is updating the new table already in between it doing each task within my SP. By fails  I mean the entire of the SP doesn't complete, I'm struggling to replicate the issue as its automated to run overnight.

Comment: @MrWing: you should edit the question to include the extra information, as comments can sometimes be missed by later readers.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any tools within SQL Server that will allow me to isolate access

[DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements are covered by transactions as well as [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) ones, so wrapping the whole process in a transaction may bu the solution there.

> Stored Procedure that is dropping, recreating and then applying keys and indexes to a table
>
> its automated to run overnight

Could you edit your question to describe *why* you are doing this that way?

If it is being run every night (or otherwise on a regular basis) this seems an unusual task to be performing. If you are just looking to optimise the indexes then you can rebuild or reorganise them without needing to drop and recreate (and even then you may want to reconsider: stale stats, fragmentation, and other issues, are not likely to be bad enough that you need to do this as regularly).

If you are dropping the whole table to clear the data (your sentence could be read as just rebuilding the indexes+keys+constraints or rebuilding everything) then using `TRUNCATE TABLE` should do the job and do so far more efficiently - no need to recreate the other objects at all. IF you can't truncate the table because there are foreign keys referring to it then you'll need to disable those and recreate them at the end of the process, being sure to wrap the process in a transaction with relevant locks to stop applications potentially creating data that breaks the constraints while they are inactive), but that should be a lot quicker than rebuilding *everything*.